# loop thyrough taxonomy names in node

Tags: loops, drupal-7, taxonomy, names

I am not a drupal expert and I am a little bit lost in taxonomies so I hope someone can help me a bit..

This bit of code displays all categories (defined in taxonomies) in a page BUT it displays them as a list of links..

```
print render ($content['field_category']);
```

I need to get a list of taxonomy names for field_category without links.. Just names.

using this code I am able to get ONE name.

```
print render ($node->field_category['und'][0]['taxonomy_term']->name);
```

Can someone help me figure out how I would get the same result that the first line renders but without links?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you use views module :
Create a Taxonomy View, then add "term field".
In field setting, uncheck "show as link" option and you will have your taxonomy list shown without links.
Hope that helps you.

Comment: Thank you. It  did help with finding my way around drupal